# Fastest way to warmup macbook when the device is very cold

Tags: hardware, hardware-recommendation

I like to go code in my backyard but sometimes my macbook gets really really cold. I wrote a python script that basically for loops thousands of times recursively doing multiplication to make the cpu work at full capacity to heat the macbook up quickly.

1. Is this damaging to the computer to put it under such intense stress while cold?
2. Are there better ways to heat up the computer?
3. Is it even bad if the macbook gets too cold?(Canadian temperature...)

Specs.

[image]

Comment: What is the lowest ambient temperature where you are using your system?

Comment: -10 degree C, hardware seems to reach around that temperature only after 5 minutes of being outside.

Comment: I haven’t noticed any issues even going down to -30 C on my recent (2015 and newer) gear - the hardware isn’t the issue in cold for me whether it’s Mac or iOS or iPadOS.

Answer (score 1):

Re: point 3

> Is it even bad if the macbook gets too cold?(Canadian temperature...)

According to Apple Support article [Keep your Mac notebook within acceptable operating temperatures](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201640), the acceptable operating temperature and humidity ranges are (emphasis mine):

> Use your Mac notebook where the ambient temperature is between 50° and 95° F (10° and 35° C). Don’t leave your Mac notebook in your car, because temperatures in parked cars can exceed this range. You should also use your Mac notebook where the relative humidity is between 0% and 95% **(noncondensing)**.

When you come indoors, condensation may form on the MacBook if the chassis is too cold, or the relative humidity indoors is high (or both). This may damage the computer, especially if there is condensation on the internal components.

Extreme cold also negatively impacts battery chemistry. From personal experience, I have had iPhones with good battery, and 50% charge suddenly power off in -10° C temperature because the battery couldn't reliably supply enough power to the device (this may not be a concern if the device is plugged in).

Answer (score 0):

I usually find it hard NOT to get it hot. Have you tried running this in your background? This should keep it at 100% and measure your CPU temperature again

https://www.geeks3d.com/gputest/

For reference, check your manual. Usually Apple recommend operating between 10° to 35°C.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn’t worry about cold, personally and would probably not try to loop the CPU since the device won’t benefit much from the energy drain. Excess heat is another story as it will permanently damage the battery and can cause issues with the display. Cold just temporarily reduces the ability of the battery to provide current so as long as the device starts - you should be good and if not, external power will solve that temporary capacity issue.

1. LCD and plastics might be marginally more brittle, but a large margin of safety is designed in to prevent them from breaking in shipping where temperatures may be cold for extended periods of time in Air and Ocean Cargo holds.
2. The absolute temperature change between -10 C and 30 C is not so large and as long as you don’t bring the cold unit into a warm and humid space.
3. Display response time and color uniformity may be slightly diminished at the lowers temperatures, but I don’t expect any lasting effects of cold operation here.

Condensation is the big problem that operating temperature ranges protect from on the low end.